# Seek bar not working in listview

Tags: audio, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have create one listview using base adapter, my problem is that when i start 1st song on listview so seekbar working fine but if i start second song on list to play then first and second buth seekbar starts.

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<String> audioList;
Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Handler durationHandler = new Handler();
public Adapter1(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> audioList) {

    this.context = mainActivity;
    this.audioList = audioList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return audioList.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View myView = convertView;
    final ImageView imgIcon, imgPlay, imgPause;
    final String fileName = audioList.get(position);
    final String path="/Music/AudioFile/";
    final TextView tvTotalTime,duration;
    final SeekBar seekbar;
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    if (myView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_adapter, null);
        imgPlay = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlay);
        imgPause = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imgPause);
        seekbar =(SeekBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        tvTotalTime =(TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalTime);
        duration =(TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        final Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
                tvTotalTime.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime)));

                double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
                duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));
                durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        };
        seekbar.setClickable(true);

        final int personPosition = position;
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
        Log.e("Checking File:", "Checking=======:" + fileName);
        imgPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Stop" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + path + fileName));
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Playing" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
                    durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
                    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                    Log.e("Checking File:", "Checking=======:" + fileName);
                }
            }
        });

        imgPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Paused" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imgPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                imgPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
    return myView;
}
```

}